# Reordering the bars from low to high

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to make a bar chart

```
ggplot(data= Dataa, aes(x = Gender, fill = Q1)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Figure 1.1", subtitle = "Distribution of national exam scores by region", y = "Count", x = "Average score for each student (MSTUDENT)") +
  theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(face="bold")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),   
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
```

I would want to order the bars, for both of the genders, ascending,

[image: Bar Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result:

1. Instead of computing the counts via `geom_bar` aggregate your data before passing it to `ggplot`
2. Arrange you data by `Gender` and count (which by default is named `n` by `dplyr::count`
3. Group by `Gender` and add an helper `id` or more precisely the rank to each `Q1` category.
4. Map the helper column on the `group` aesthetic so that the bars are ordered according to rank.

Besides that we have to switch to `geom_col` and map the manually calculated counts on the `y` aesthetic.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Aggregate data, arrange and add helper variable
Dataa1 <- Dataa %>% 
  count(Gender, Q1) %>% 
  arrange(Gender, n) %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())

ggplot(data= Dataa1, aes(x = Gender, y = n, group = id, fill = Q1)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Figure 1.1", subtitle = "Distribution of national exam scores by region", y = "Count", x = "Average score for each student (MSTUDENT)") +
  theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(face="bold")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),   
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

Dataa <- data.frame(
  Gender = rep(c("Kvinner", "Mann"), 100),
  Q1 = sample(paste0("Bank", 1:10), 200, replace = TRUE)
)
Dataa$Q1 <- factor(Dataa$Q1, levels = paste0("Bank", 1:10))
```